# Lazy Adapter for the Call Logs

Tags: java, android, android-lazyadapter

I have created an application that can show call logs. I am using `LazyAdapter` class.  I am showing an icon according to the call type: `Missed` / `Incoming` / `Outgoing`. This part is not working properly. The display of text like name, number, date and time is showing just fine except the Call type?

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
  public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
  {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d)
{
    activity = a;
    data=d;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() 
{       
    return data.size();         
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position)
{

    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.callist, null);


    TextView name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name); 
    TextView number = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.phone_number); 
    TextView date = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.date); 
    TextView time = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.time);
    TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); 
    ImageView callType = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.calType);
    ImageView clock = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.Clock);


    HashMap<String, String> pro = new HashMap<String, String>();
    pro = data.get(position);


    if((pro.get(ListOfCall.contactName)!=null))
    {
        name.setText(pro.get(ListOfCall.contactName));      
    }
    else
    {
        name.setText("Unknown"); 
    }   
    number.setText(pro.get(ListOfCall.phone));
    date.setText(pro.get(ListOfCall.DateOfCall));
    time.setText(pro.get(ListOfCall.TimeOfCall));
    String  type = pro.get(ListOfCall.typeofCall);


    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("OUTGOING"))
    {
        callType.setImageResource(R.drawable.outgoing); 
        duration.setText(pro.get(ListOfCall.durationOfCall));
    }
    else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("INCOMING"))
    {
        callType.setImageResource(R.drawable.incoming); 
        duration.setText(pro.get(ListOfCall.durationOfCall));
    }
    else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("MISSED"))
    {

        callType.setImageResource(R.drawable.missed);   
        duration.setVisibility(4);
        clock.setVisibility(4);
    }
    return vi;

}

}
```

I am not really sure where the problem is coming because I am able get correct results in the `arraylist` called data in the top. Things change when I move the arraylist to `Hashmap` called pro.

Again the values are coming up properly except the call type and it's corresponding images are not coming up.

Can somebody help me out to fix this up?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the conditions that were in LazyAdapter class didn't work as required. Removed the condition and added them in before class that was sending values to LazyAdapter class.

Works fine now!!

Thanks!